# How to disable an input box by clicking a button using vue js 2.0

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, disabled-input, vue-directives

How can I  disable an input box via clicking a button and toggling it using vuejs 2.0

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can bind `disabled`, see an example:

```js
new Vue({

  el: '#app',
  data: {
    isDisabled: false
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">

  <input type="text" :disabled="isDisabled">
  <button @click="isDisabled = !isDisabled">Click</button>

</div>
```